# How to make object variable changes remain after ForEach loop. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, mongoose

I am trying to generate a Data object that I can use to create new documents in my MongoDB database using mongoose in NodeJS.

This is the snippet of code:

```
console.log(RecipeData.ingredients);
RecipeData.spices.forEach(function(spice){
    module.exports.findSpiceByName(spice, function(err, res){
        if (err){
            return callback(err);
        }
        RecipeData.ingredients.push(res._id);
        return callback(null, RecipeData);
    });
});

console.log(RecipeData.ingredients);
```

basically, i have RecipeData that is a object with a few attributes. the main ones in this case is spice and ingredients. both of which are list of Strings.

- I want to check RecipeData.spice:

  - if there is a element in the list: (the element would be the name of the spice)

    - I want to find the spice associated to that name in my Spices Collection and add its _id to my RecipeData.ingredients permanently

both the console.log's have the same output when they shouldn't in the example I am using to test this code.

Any idea why the variable RecipeData.ingredients is not changing outside the ForEach loop?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an asynchronous programming issue. Though you didn't post the source, I'm assuming that `module.exports.findSpiceByName` is asynchronous, where `forEach` is not, so the `forEach` finishes and your second `console.log` runs before your `findSpiceByName` calls have time to complete.

One way to resolve this would be to use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and then wait for all of them to complete before trying to inspect the ingredients:

```
var spicePromises = RecipeData.spices.map(function(spice) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        module.exports.findSpiceByName(spice, function(err, res) {
           if (err) {
              return reject(err);
           }
           resolve(res._id);
        });
    });
});

Promise.all(spicePromises).then(function(ingredients) {
  Recipe.ingredients = ingredients;
  console.log(RecipeData.ingredients);
});
```

Comment: that is actually absolutely true. these `console.logs` run before the ones in `findSpiceByName`. How can I fix this? Although regardless of the console logs, I'm sure the variable is not changing since I try to add the data object to the Collection later where its not updated as needed.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example of how you could get around this issue

Comment: this didnt quite help because the same thing kept happening. So to avoid this issue, I changed the data after the collection was already in the database. this way i was able to directly update the database when there was a change. Thanks for your help though. :)